# Best Way To Use SKLearn Private Classes

Tags: python, class, methods, scikit-learn, private

I'm currently solving [an issue](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/issues/2240) which involves replacing a class which we have been using in our application but from v0.22 the class has been made private and should not be imported as it'll be removed in v0.24. I'm looking for the best method by which we can use the classes without importing them from sklearn.

I'm thinking of replicating the classes in our own code and just use the public API available from sklearn to implement them. I would like to know if there are any better methods for the same?

The classes we are using are `LinearClassifierMixin` and `SparseCoefMixin` which are available in [`sklearn/linear_model/_base.py`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py) and use public APIs in their own methods.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for the same seems to be finding classes that inherit in a similar manner the classes we are trying to use and thereafter use them.

The same is being done here: https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/pull/2328